# How to trigger AWS Lambda just once on multiple S3 notifications

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

We are designing a pipeline. We get a number of raw files which come into S3 buckets and then we apply a schema and then save them as parquet.

As of now we are triggering a lambda function for each file written but ideally we would like to start this process only after all the files are written. How we can we trigger the lambda just once?

Answer (score 2):

I encourage you to use an alternative that maintains the separation between the publisher (whoever is writing) and the subscriber (you). The publisher tells you when things are written; it's your responsibility to choose when to process those things. The neat pattern here would be for the publisher to write its files in batches and publish **manifests** for you to trigger on: i.e. a list which says "I just wrote all these things, you can find them in these places". Since you don't have that / can't change the publisher, I suggest the following:

1. Send the notifications from the publisher to an [SQS queue](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/).
2. Schedule your lambda to run on a schedule; how often is determined by how long you're willing to delay ingestion. If you want data to be delayed at most 5min between being published and getting ingested by your system, set your lambda to trigger every 4min. You can use Cloudwatch notifications for this.
3. When your lambda runs, poll the queue. Keep going until you accumulate the maximum amount of notifications, X, you want to process in one go, or the queue is empty.
4. Process. If the queue wasn't empty when you stopped polling, immediately trigger another lambda execution.

Things to keep in mind on the above:

1. As written, it's not parallel, so if your rate of lambda execution is slower than the rate at which the queue fills up, you'll need to 1. run more frequently or 2. insert a load-balancing step: a lambda that is triggered on a schedule, polls the queue, and calls as many processing lambdas as necessary so that each one gets X notifications.
2. SNS in general and SQS non-FIFO queues specifically don't guarantee exactly-once delivery. They can send you duplicate notifications. Make sure you can handle duplicate processing cleanly.

Comment: Thanks, I will explore more on your suggestion.

Comment: @MyStack Why do you not recommend triggered the Lambda function directly from the Amazon SQS message? This would avoid the need to schedule the Lambda function.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein that's a good question. Its biggest limitation is that the max batch size is 10 ([see docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html)). Otherwise, its a fine (less flexible) alternative to the above, which saves you having to schedule your own lambda invocations, but still requires some finicky config.

Answer (score 1):

Hook your Lambda up to a Webhook (API Gateway) and then just call it from your client app once your client app is done.

Comment: I am quite new to the AWS and API, I will explore on your suggestion. Do you have any web links so that I can read and understand the webhook (API gateways) solution?

Answer (score 0):

Solutions:

1. Zip all files together, Lambda unzip it
2. create a UI code and send files one by one, trigger lambda from it when the last one is sent
3. Lambda check files, if didn't find all files, silent quit. if it finds all files, then handle all files in one thread

Comment: Too big files so it may take long time to compress and uncompress. Also we do not have control on the source system which just copies all the files into our S3 bucket. Point 3 may be able to do but its does not look like elegant solution.

Comment: Note that zip (and other such tools) can be used as mere containers, without compression stages. Of course, creating the file has costs, including deciding what to do about potentially duplicating the storage size.